# How to apply Custome Font in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor, custom-font

I am Developing a Wordpress site for Local Client Who need his Site to display in Tamil(Indian Language) but in Wordpress Editor I can not Find That font. So How Can I done this?

Comment: you can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398342/adding-font-face-to-ckeditor)

Comment: Thanks empiric for reply

Answer (score 0):

First Add CKEditor and Do Following Steps As mention below:

-Add **fonts file** into same directory of ckeditor where **content.css** exist

-Add following line to **config.js** after function end

```
  config.contentsCss = [ CKEDITOR.getUrl('contents.css'), 'contents.css' ]
```

-Add **font family name** into this funtion at last like I have **"Aabohi-Tamil/aabohiregular"**

Where "aabohiregular" is name of font-family set in css file and "Aabohi-Tamil is name display in Select Box"

```
CKEDITOR.config.font_names="Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;Georgia/Georgia, serif;Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;Aabohi-Tamil/aabohiregular";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are well!!!!

i think below link will help you to change your website in local language.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-in-other-languages/

Comment: Kaushal I dont want to install wordpress in local language,  I want to display content of the site in local language. and i am able to write in local language in wditor..

But thanks for replay