# How to add tamil font into ck editor?

Tags: jquery, css, ckeditor

This is the first time, i am using ck editor in my project.

Need to add new  fonts in ck editor combo fonts list.

I am waiting for your answer

advance thanks friends..

Comment: Please elaborate further to get better responses.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of [adding @font-face to CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398342/adding-font-face-to-ckeditor)

Long story short: You have to add the name/location to your config file and you need to add the @font-face to your css.

Comment: Font name added in ck editor fonts list but not working ? I'm using Tamil Aishwarya font