# DJango - Add custom font to Ckeditor

Tags: django

I want to add my font to `CKEditor`. I spent a time for searching in internet but all solutions not working for me.after using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398342/adding-font-face-to-ckeditor) added  font label to combobox but my text not changed after selecting font.

this is my code

ckeditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.contentsCss = 'fonts.css';
    config.font_names = 'BBCNassim;' + config.font_names;
};
```

ckeditor/fonts.css

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: 'BBCNassim';  
    src: url( ../fonts/BBCNassim.TTF );
    src: local("BBCNassim"), url("../fonts/BBCNassim.TTF") format("truetype");  
}
```

and directory of BBCNassim.TTF is ckeditor/fonts/BBCNassim.TTF

Edited.

I saw my browser requests(status = 404). my site can not load fonts.css. i using django framework.

browser loaded http://127.0.01:8000/admin/app/post/2/fonts.css.

Comment: Is the font being loaded successfully, i.e. if you view the Network Requests in the Browser developer tools is the font file there?

Comment: So you don't have the correct directory path then?

Answer (score 2):

I am used django-text-ckeditor and djangocms. I had exactly same issue. Please attend to steps and do them step by step.

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> open terminal.
2. go to project directory and active your virtualenv if you use virtualenv.
3. type `python manage.py shell`
4. then type `from django.conf import settings`
5. then type `settings.CKEDITOR_SETTINGS` to see default django-text-ckeditor settings. this setting is similar this:

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    'allowedContent': True,
    'autoParagraph': False,
    'baseHref': '/media/',
    'enterMode': 'CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR',
    'extraAllowedContent': 'style;*;*{*}',
    'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl': '/filebrowser/',
    'language': '{{ language }}',
    'removePlugins': 'stylesheetparser,about,showblocks,language,form,flash,iframe',
    'skin': 'moonocolor',
    'toolbar': 'toolbar_Basic',
}
```

6. now you can define `CKEDITOR_SETTINGS` in your `settings.py` and override it.
7. now you need to add `font_names` key to `CKEDITOR_SETTINGS` similar this:
   `CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = { ..., ..., 'font_names': 'IRANSans; Yekan; Bnasim; Bkoodak;, ..., }`
   If you do this 7 step, fonts combo initialized with custom font names. I kow you do this correctly.

**Note** that if you have these fonts in `statics` and theme defined in your css by `@font-face` you can use fonts in ckeditor.
For example this is my `farsifonts.css` that my fonts defined in it:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Naskh';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Regular/DroidNaskh-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Regular/DroidNaskh-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Regular/DroidNaskh-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Regular/DroidNaskh-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/DriodArabi.loginColumnscNaskh/Regular/DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Naskh';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Bold/DroidNaskh-Bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Bold/DroidNaskh-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Bold/DroidNaskh-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Bold/DroidNaskh-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/DriodArabicNaskh/Bold/DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Regular/DroidKufi-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Regular/DroidKufi-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Regular/DroidKufi-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Regular/DroidKufi-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Regular/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Bold/DroidKufi-Bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Bold/DroidKufi-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Bold/DroidKufi-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Bold/DroidKufi-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/DroidArabicKufi/Bold/DroidKufi-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bnasim';
    src: url('../fonts/BBCNasim/BBCNasim.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/BBCNasim/BBCNasim.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/BBCNasim/BBCNasim.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/BBCNasim/BBCNasim.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/BBCNasim/BBCNasim.svg#BBCNasim') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bkoodak';
    src: url('../fonts/BKoodak/BKoodak.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/BKoodak/BKoodak.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/BKoodak/BKoodak.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/BKoodak/BKoodak.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/BKoodak/BKoodak.svg#BKoodak') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bnazanin';
    src: url('../fonts/BNazanin/BNazanin.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/BNazanin/BNazanin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/BNazanin/BNazanin.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/BNazanin/BNazanin.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/BNazanin/BNazanin.svg#BNazanin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yekan';
    src: url('../fonts/WeblogmaYekan.eot?#') format('eot'),  /* IE6â€“8 */
    url('../fonts/WeblogmaYekan.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/WeblogmaYekan.ttf') format('truetype');  /* Saf3â€”5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}



@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb_Bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb_Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff2/IRANSansWeb_Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff/IRANSansWeb_Bold.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/ttf/IRANSansWeb_Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb_Medium.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb_Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff2/IRANSansWeb_Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff/IRANSansWeb_Medium.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/ttf/IRANSansWeb_Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb_Light.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb_Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff2/IRANSansWeb_Light.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff/IRANSansWeb_Light.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/ttf/IRANSansWeb_Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff2/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/ttf/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/iransans/eot/IRANSansWeb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff2/IRANSansWeb.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/woff/IRANSansWeb.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/iransans/ttf/IRANSansWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: VazirCode;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/vazir-code/Vazir-Code.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/vazir-code/Vazir-Code.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/vazir-code/Vazir-Code.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/vazir-code/Vazir-Code.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

***Note***: your fonts not served. maybe you have one problems of this list:

- maybe your fonts can not served. check how you set fonts path in your_style.css
- maybe you need to collect static files with this command `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS` to this:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'contentsCss': STATIC_URL + "fonts.css",
        'font_names': 'IranSans/IranSans;Lalezar/Lalezar'

    },
}
```

`IranSans/IranSans` is on this format: `FontNameToShow/RealFontName`

this is `static/fonts.css` file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: IranSans;
    src: url("iransansweb.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Lalezar;
    src: url("Lalezar.ttf");
}

body {
    font-family: IranSans, sans-serif;
}
```

I set a default font in the `body` tag.
I hope I helped you in solving your problem.