# CKeditor : Use another language font

Tags: javascript, unicode, ckeditor

I'm trying to use sinhala font with ckeditor. I tried adding multiple sinhala fonts (Unicode and not unicode) fonts to editor according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398342/adding-font-face-to-ckeditor),

**config.js**

```
config.contentsCss = [ CKEDITOR.getUrl('contents.css'),'fonts.css' ] ;
config.font_names = 'Iskolapota/iskolapota;' + config.font_names;
config.font_names = 'Amalee/amalee;' + config.font_names;
config.font_names = 'FM Abhaya/fm_abhay;' + config.font_names;
```

**fonts.css**

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'Iskolapota';
src: url('../../../font/iskolapota.ttf');
src: local("iskolapota"), url("../../../font/iskolapota.ttf") 

format("truetype");
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'Amalee';
    src: url('../../../font/amalee.ttf');
    src: local("amalee"), url("../../../font/amalee.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'FM Abhaya';
    src: url('../../../font/fm_abhay.ttf');
    src: local("fm_abhay"), url("../../../font/fm_abhay.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

But not worked. I can still see only English letters in the editor.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKEq5.png)

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is there any error message given in the developers console? Is the font even loaded properly?

Comment: No there are no error messages

Comment: So the font is loaded, but not displayed?

Comment: Yes. Only English letters

Comment: And that is what you see in the network tab of your browser or only in the CKEditor instance?

Comment: Guys sorry for the late response. I changed to summernote. It worked as a expected. Thank you all